# Google Chrome 6, content retrieval broken?

Tags: google-chrome

I just updated to Google Chrome 6, and the web is falling apart around me.

Our internal web-based support system just gives me:

```
This webpage is not available.

The webpage at <url> might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

  More information on this error
Below is the original error message

Error 9 (net::ERR_UNEXPECTED): Unknown error.
```

The captcha image on [Skeet's latest blog entry](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction.aspx) comes up as a broken image:

[image: Skeet Captcha, broken by Chrome 6?]

Of course, I can't actually see the image here either, since it is equally broken for me.

**Note**: I have of course verified the relevant sites with IE8 and FireFox and they work and look fine in all other browsers. They also looked fine yesterday, in Chrome 5, and our internal support system has had no updates or whatnot for a long time so I doubt anything happened that made it break. Indeed, it works fine on other machines here that still has Chrome 5 installed.

These are just two examples of a myriad of websites that are either subtly broken or just plain doesn't give me any content at all.

Does anyone else have problems with Chrome 6, or is it just me?

---

**More info**: I tried disabling all extensions, no change. What else can I tweak that might impact this? I checked proxy settings, all checkboxes unchecked, so no auto-discovery enabled either (which I know has caused some performance problems for me in the past.)

I also cleared my cache. No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have the same issue as well, and it happens on youtube, gmail or other sites. The only thing that works is to close Chrome and restart.. This is super frustrating

Answer (score 2):

Ok, for the moment it seems I've found out what the problem is, at least for some sites, I will continue to try to find a solution to the rest, and check each update to Chrome.

The problem with the Jon Skeet blog is apparently known to him, judging by the comments on the blog post I linked to, so apparently that's not new, although it works on a different machine here in Chrome 5, for some odd reason.

Our internal support system uses integrated security, so Chrome tries to send authentication information, and bungles it up, so apparently the new proxy system they added at some point in Chrome 6 doesn't handle this integrated security all that well. I could circumvent it by adding the username and password in the URL, but that's not a good permanent solution.